# Using objectFilter to exclude Vyatta's

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using objectFilter to get all hardware devices with a ACTIVE Public IP, but want to exclude all Vyatta devices.  I am using the following URL:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[globalIdentifier,primaryIpAddress,networkManagementIpAddress,hardwareFunction,primaryBackendIpAddress,frontendNetworkComponents]&objectFilter={"hardware":{"frontendNetworkComponents":{"status":{"operation":"ACTIVE"}},"manufacturer":{"operation":"!=Vyatta"}}}
```

I am still getting Vyatta devices returned. How do I exclude Vyatta devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardware object contains a property called "networkGatewayMemberFlag" this property tells whether the device is a gateway (or Vyatta) server.

but I am afraid this property cannot be used in a filter. So you need to add that property in your object mask, and once you get the response, you need to use your own code to filter the data using that property.

try this rquest:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[operatingSystem,networkGatewayMemberFlag,globalIdentifier,primaryIpAddress,networkManagementIpAddress,hardwareFunction,primaryBackendIpAddress,frontendNetworkComponents]&objectFilter={"hardware":{"frontendNetworkComponents":{"status":{"operation":"ACTIVE"}},"operatingSystem":{"softwareLicense":{"softwareDescription":{"manufacturer":{"operation":"!=Vyatta"}}}}}}
```

Regards

Comment: Why isn't the "manufacturer" filter working? Is this one of those you see it in the response, but can't filter on it?

Comment: that property is not listed for a Hardware object http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Hardware. I only see "manufacturerSerialNumber" property that's why the filter does not work

Comment: I update my response using the manufaturer of the OS installed in the server maybe that one can help you

Comment: Thank you, let me check that.

Comment: I looked at operatingSystemReferenceCode as a filter. Here is new URL: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?objectMask=mask[globalIdentifier,primaryIpAddress,networkManagementIpAddress,hardwareFunction,primaryBackendIpAddress,hardwareStatus,datacenter,lastTransaction,location,memoryCapacity,processorCoreAmount,operatingSystemReferenceCode,hourlyBillingFlag,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,networkVlans,frontendNetworkComponents]&objectFilter={"hardware":{"frontendNetworkComponents":{"status":{"operation":"ACTIVE"}, "operatingSystemReferenceCode":{"operation":"!~VYATTA"}}}}

Comment: Great I will thank you if you can mark the answer as the corect and vote